# How can I use regex to get matches on each side of the equal sign for the string (test1)=(tes=)t2)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to capture two matches between an equal sign: `(test1)=(test2)` such that match1 = test1 and match2 = test2.  So far I have been able to use `/\([\s\S\)\(]*?\)/gmi` which mostly works UNLESS there is an additional close paren on either side of the equal sign, ie:  (test1)=(te)st2).

What regex could I create that would allow me to successfully wind up with two matches given the below:

```
"(test1)=(tes=)t2)".match( /\([\s\S\)\(]*?\)/gmi ) === ["test1", "tes=)t2"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the examples in the question and if supported using lookarounds, you can assert that the closing parenthesis can not contain `=` or `)` to the right.

Note that you can omit the `/m` flag as there are no anchors in the pattern, and you can also omit the `/i` flag as the pattern does not specifically matches upper or lowercase characters.

```js
let regex = /(?<=\().*?(?=\)(?![^\s=)]))/g;
let str = "(test1)=(tes=)t2)";
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Or using a capture group without a lookbehind assertion:

```js
let regex = /\((.*?)\)(?![^\s=])/g;
let str = "(test1)=(tes=)t2)";
const result = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result) === JSON.stringify(["test1", "tes=)t2"]));
```